# html content outside of div appearing inside of div

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble with the action of my DIVS.  Basically I have a div and outside of the div if I put some html text it still shows up inside the div.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  If someone could take a peek I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

html:

```
<div id="content">

            <p>  To submit <?php echo $_SESSION['sight_type']?> sightings, choose a location type.</p>

        <div id = "form_location_type" >`

        <form method="POST" action="location_type_input.php">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="location_type" value="new"  /></td><td><p> New location</p></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="location_type" value="saved" /></td><td><p> Saved location</p></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Continue"></td></tr>
            <table>
        </form>
        </div>     <!-- End form_location_type div -->
         THIS SHOULD BE OUTSIDE ABOVE DIV BUT IT PRINTS INSIDE                   
    </div> <!-- End content div -->

    <div id="footer"> <?php include 'footer.php'; ?> </div> <!-- End footer div -->
```

css (most relevant is the very last commented section)

```
html { height: 100%; }
body, html { min-height: 100%; height: 100%;margin : 0;
    padding : 0; }
/*html, body {
    height:auto
    height: 100%; }/* Required */



body {


    width:100%;
    line-height : 1.8em;
    color : #000000;
    background : #F5F5FF; 
    }

#container {

    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    width : 800px;
    margin : 0 auto 0 auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    background : #FFFFCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; /* shadow border */
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    }
#footer {
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 800px;
    background : #FFFFCC;
    font : 75% "Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif; 

    } 

/* form on form_location_type.php */   
#form_location_type {

margin: 0 auto;
background:white;
border:solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you close your table properly:

```
<table>
    ...
</table>
```

That seems to be the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RDGuY/2/

Comment: That was it.  Arrgh, I missed that about a billion times.  Will mark correct as soon as time limit expires.  8 mins... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed table properly.

Add

```
</table>
```

instead of the

```
<table>
```

at the end of form_location_type div

Additionally try to add some bottom padding in form_location_type div:

Add the following code in your CSS:

```
#form_location_type {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Now check if the text is separated from form div???